# When the before_action is triggerred in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is a example of a controller with `before_action` in Rails app:

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  include Module1
  before_action :action1

  def controller_method
  ...
  end

  private
  def private_method
  ...
  end
end

Module Module1
  def module_method
   ...
  end   
end
```

My understanding of `before_action` is that any calls to `controller_method` and/or `private_method` in the controller and/or `module_method` `included` from `Module1` will trigger execution of `before_action action1`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

No, not all calls, just the actions(route calls), usually private methods will not be called as an action, so private methods will not trigger *_action callback. In your example:

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  include Module1
  before_action :action1

  def controller_method
     // when you call public, protected, or private methods here,
     // the *_action callback will not called
     // becouse it not a call delegated by routes
     private_method 
  end

  private
  def private_method
  ...
  end
end
```

Note comments I added in controller_method. When you reach a routes like "/exaple/contoller_method", the contoller_method will be called, before that, action1 will be called as a before_action. But when you call a method inside contoller_method, the before_action will not be triggerd for this inner call.

Comment: A naming route will trigger the `before_action` as well? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the relevant action will trigger the before_action, if you set so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

All methods included from `Module1` will become part of the `ExampleController` really, so it would be the same as if you defined those methods in that class. When you call any method that is included from the module the callback for the before action will be executed first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you correct. Anyway, you can define an "only" clause too. And remember that will work only with declared methods.

best!